# Count column SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, count

I am looking to create a second column which counts all the columns with a number >= 2.

```
    Total 
    2.03
    2.00
    2.00
    1.38
    1.33
    1.32
    1.21
```

Expected result

```
    Total           Count column                   
    2.03                 3
    2.00
    2.00
    1.38
    1.33
    1.32
    1.21
```

I have looked at SUMIF and COUNTIF

```
 =Sum(IIf(Fields!Total.Value >= "2" , 1, 0)
```

But i just get the SSRS cannot create report error.

Can anyone help? thanks

Comment: Your are missing a `)` at the end of the expression. If this was just a typo and your code is not as shown above then you may need to specify the scope of the sum. Something like `=Sum(IIf(Fields!Total.Value >= "2" , 1, 0),"DataSet1")`

Comment: yes, this worked. thanks!